# jquery handling server side errors

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, jquery-validate

How can I use Jquery to handle server side errors?
This is my scenario. I have to validate my JSO form initially. For this I am using `.validate()` from jquery. Once all these validations are done and when I click submit I have to validate `userId` and `pwd` field. If success I goto confirm page else stay in the same page and show an inline error. To achieve this I do not want to reload but want to use `jquery`/`ajax` options. I tried the following code but it wouldn't work.

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        //...


        ..//

        $("#aID").validate({
                rules: {
                    reason: "required",
                    aic: "required",
    pwd: {
required: true,
            remote: function() { 
                 remote: {
                    url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/tax/pwdChkAjax.do",
                    dataType: "post",
                    data: {
                        pwd: function() {
                               return $("#pwd").val();
                           }
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                            alert("111");
                        }
                    }
                }

                },
                messages: {
                    reason:"Please select a reason code.",
                    aic: "Please select a credit AIC."
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    if (aLen.length == 0)) {
                        $('#pDiv').text('Please enter password.');   
                        $("#pwd").focus();  
                        return false;
                    }

                     var options = {
                        url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/abc/aTax.do",
                        beforeSubmit: function (data, set, options) {  
                            alert("Inside beforesubmit");          
                        },
                        success: function (param1, param2, param3) {            
                        },
                        error: function (param1, param2, param3) 
                        {   
                        alert(param3);
                                if (param3 == "Unauthorized") 
                                    $('#aDiv').text('Invalid Password');
                                if (param3 == "Forbidden") 
                                $('#cDiv').text('Invalid 2nd Password');

                        }
                    };        
                    // submit the form
                    $(form).ajaxSubmit(options);
                    return false;
                }
            }); 
         });

         <form:form id="aID" action="aTax.do" commandName="aForm">
         <DIV class="btn-group">
                <button id="submitId"  type="submit" class="defaultButton">Submit
                </button>
                <button id="resetId"  
                    type="reset" class="defaultButton">Reset
                </button>
            </DIV>
        </form:form>
```

Controller class

```
     @RequestMapping(value="/abc/aTax.do", method=RequestMethod.POST) 
        public String aTax(@Valid aForm command, BindingResult result, 
                 Model model, HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {  

         //...
         pwdAuthenticate();
         ..//
         return "aTaxConfirm";       
        }

    private void authenticateUser(User user, AForm aForm, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
    {
    try{
     userAuthenticateService.authenticateUser(aForm.getId(), aForm.getPwd());
    }catch(AException e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception is ...."+e);      
                        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);

                }
    } 

@RequestMapping(value="tax/pwdChkAjax.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    private Boolean pwdChkAjax(String pwd, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
    {

        try{
            userAuthenticate.authenticate("abc", pwdOverride);
} catch (AuthenticationException e) {

                return false;
            }
            return true;
    }
```

Mapping:

```
<definition name="aTaxConfirm" extends="baseTransLayout" >
             <put-attribute name="heading" value="Tax Confirmation" />
             <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/view/jsp/abc/aTaxConfirm.jsp" />
      </definition>
```

Comment: What exactly does *"would not work"* mean?  And where is the code of the ***rendered*** `form`?

Comment: I meant validations works fine and userId and pwd validation happens too. Controller returns the view. I will update controller code. Once that is done the page is not rendered it just stays in submit.

Comment: If you see the controller code if userId/pwd validation fails response.setStatus returns error back to ajax call and it is handled. But when success it returns "aTaxConfirm";. I get the sysout just before the return but view isnt rendered

Answer (score 0):

You have a stray closing brace.

```
$("#aID").validate({
    rules: {
        reason: "required",
        aic: "required"
            } // <- REMOVE THIS
    },
    messages: {
        reason:"Please select a reason code.",
        aic: "Please select a credit AIC."
    }, 
    ....
```

This should have given you a console error.

---

> Once all these validations are done and when i click submit I have to validate userId and pwd field.

Why after validations are done?  You should be using [the `remote` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) to validate the `userId` and `pwd` field along with all the other field validations.

---

EDIT based on this comment in response to "What exactly does *"would not work" mean?"*

> I meant validations works fine and userId and pwd validation happens too. Controller returns the view. I will update controller code. Once that is done the page is not rendered it just stays in submit.

That's because your `submitHandler` code is not submitting the form.  It's merely submitting the login credentials via Ajax.  Whenever you use the `submitHandler` option, you totally block and over-ride the default `action` URL as set by your `form` attribute.

If you take the previous advice and use the `remote` method to evaluate the login credentials along with the other fields, you can remove the `submitHandler` entirely.

The following will happen:

1. All fields are validated as per their rules.  The login and passwords fields, using the `remote` rule will be evaluated automatically via Ajax.
2. When the form passes validation, it will "submit" normally as per your `action` attribute, and the page will reload to this `action` URL and show your view as per your script at this URL.

NOTES about `remote` method:

- The server response **must** be valid JSON.  No exception.
- If the server response is `true`, then this field will pass validation.
- If the server response is `false`, `undefined`, or `null`, then this field will fail validation, and the default validation error message will be used.
- If the server response is a string, then this field will fail validation AND this string becomes the validation error message.

Comment: I have changed the code and added controller code. I will look into remote methos validation. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your time in replying. I am trying remote calls using jquery but its not getting triggered. Added my code above.

Comment: With the code change all validation except pwd is working. Remote is not getting triggered. Not sure if my jquery code is right since there is no trigger like "required" or something like that or it just works with field value.

Comment: @JNPW, every rule on every field, including remote, is simply triggered by user events like keyup and focusout.

Comment: Added required constraint but still its not getting triggered. Can you help me with the code.

Comment: @JNPW, have you installed [the jQuery Validate plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org)?